# How to implement directory selection in web application not file selection jsf/java

Tags: javascript, jsf, jsf-2

need to implement directory selection in web application using jsf/java not file selection

we have input tag  this will lead to select the file but we need only directory selection and we need to capture the directory path.

is there any best of capturing the directory path/location in web application...?

Comment: maybe this can help you https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JFileChooser.html

Comment: You mean selecting on the *client* side? In the browser? An `input` field is for capturing a file and transferring its content. You can't do that with a directory. If you just want to capture the directory *path*, an `input` field won't help you, and you need to find something you can do in JavaScript, Flash or an Applet (the latter is hardly supported by browsers nowadays).